# States: Approximate Unit

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

Consider a state: $\omega\geq0$

Especially one has: $\sup\omega(E^2)=\|\omega\|$

Can it actually fail to be a proper limit?

The problem is that the square is not operator-monotonic:
$$A,B\geq0:\quad A\leq B\nRightarrow A^2\leq B^2$$
But that seems crucial when extracting from the enclosing inequality:
$$|\omega(A)|\leftarrow|\omega(AE)|\leq\omega(A^*A)\omega(E^2)\leq\|\omega\|_+\omega(E^2)\leq\|\omega\|_+^2\leq\|\omega\|^2$$
Does somebody have an alternative or a counterexample?

Instead, the norm-identity follows from: $\lim\omega(E)=\sup\omega(E)=\|\omega\|_+=\|\omega\|$

*(Besides, Bratelli & Robinson seem to have a tiny mistake here in their proof.)*